# Function executes when maximizing the window

Tags: jquery, css, triggers, bootstrap-5, reveal.js

I have the following script which redirects the user to another slide within my presentation when  scrolling to the bottom of the page. ( i am using Reveal.js )

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("#creation").on("scroll", function () {
    if (
      Math.round($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight(), 10) >=
      Math.round($(this)[0].scrollHeight, 10)
    ) {
      location.hash = "#film";
    }
  });
});
```

If the browser it's not in fullscreen and the user has scrolled down a bit, then makes the window fullscreen again, the script will automatically trigger.

Can someone help me avoiding this behaviour when resizing the window to fullscreen?

Comment: I'm guessing, if your script did not run, then when the user has mostly scrolled down, then *maximises* the window, the maximise includes making the window taller and the browser window is then at the bottom of the page - ie after maximising, without your code, the user can't scroll down anyway - ie maximising means your page *is* at the bottom - ie your code/page works as expected.  In which case, how would the user then "scroll down" to get to the bottom (as they're already at the bottom)?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all of your code. I wonder if this is a case where you need to wrap your script with $(document).ready(function() {  your code });

Comment: @fix OPs code is already wrapped in doc ready  `jQuery(function ($) {` and, if not, would do nothing if it ran before #creation existed, otherwise the doc.ready would/does do nothing if OPs code is at the end of body.

Comment: You could try `debounce`-ing the scroll function - but some debugging on `$(this).scrollTop()`, `$(this).innerHeight()` and `$(this)[0].scrollHeight` would probably tell you what's going on / why.   And as @fix states - seeing this in "action" would help us solve it - can you [edit] to provide a complete snippet that (with some user instructions) demonstrates the issue?  See [mcve].